# Errors happen when I run the jar file in terminal

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface

I made libcc.so from my test.cpp in ubuntu, and the content of test.cpp is linked with ffmpeg and opencv libraries. After making the libcc.so, it's loaded in JNItest2.java.

JNItest2.java:

```
public class JNItest2 {
  public native void helloworld();
  static{   
      String libPath= "/home/sun/workspace/JNItest2/src";
      System.setProperty("java.library.path",libPath);
      String Path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
      System.out.println("java.library.path=" + Path);
      System.loadLibrary("cc");         
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){        
     new JNItest2().helloworld();
  }
}
```

However, JNItest2.java can run on Eclipse, the exported jar file can't run in terminal.

Error Message in terminal:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test in 
java.library.path at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) at 
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) at 
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) at JNItest2.<clinit>
(JNItest2.java:23)
```

Does anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks, Hsiu

Comment: Make up your mind. Your source code says `"cc"`, but the error message says `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here for a sample related to JNI development:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

This is a very simple app where you can take a look at all required elements for running JNI based codes.

In your case:

- make sure to put so file in LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- if you want to use ffmpeg stuff in your code make sure to check out these two samples as well:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/
https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo023

Comment: Thanks you, my problem is solved by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.